# GetGlobalVariable array de resultado

Tags: javascript, testes, testes-de-unidade, postman, testes-automatizados

Boa noite, eu estou tentando fazer uma variável pra usar em outro request e estou testando.

Eu fiz um array com o atributo código vindo do meu payload, contém 4 códigos de 1 a 4 então o meu array são de 4 posições. Eu fiz uma variável pra salvar os valores do Array.

Quando eu chamo o GetGlobal dentro da mesma função a onde eu fiz isso, o retorno dos arrays esta correto, de 1 a 4.

Porém se eu chamo o GetGlobal em outro método ou fora da função ele simplesmente me retorna tudo 4 e não o array com as posições, alguém pode me ajudar? Eu gostaria que aparecesse 1,2,3,4 e não só o numero 4.

```
let responseJson = JSON.parse(responseBody);
let array = [];

pm.test("Testing",function()
{
    for(var value in responseJson)
    {
        trab = responseJson[value].code;
        pm.globals.set("testCode",trab);
        console.log(pm.globals.get("testCode");
    }
});
```

O Resultado é: 1,2,3,4.

```
pm.test("Testing 2",function()
{
    for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        console.log(pm.globals.get("testCode");
    }
});
```

O Resultado é 4,4,4,4 e não 1,2,3,4.

Comment: É que não lembro bem agora, mas me parece que quando você chama um `for` de forma assíncrona ele vai sempre retornar o último valor processado.

Comment: Daniel, note que no primeiro teste você modifica 4 vezes a global `testCode`. O valor que irá permanecer nela é o último atribuído, que é `4`.

Portanto, no segundo teste, visto que você não está fazendo mais nenhuma atribuição ao `testCode`, o valor dele continua sendo sempre `4`.

De qualquer forma, não ficou muito claro qual seu objetivo no segundo teste. Por quê você gostaria que o output dele fosse o mesmo do primeiro teste?